# Backbone.js - list of 'out of the box' events?

Tags: backbone.js

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something (quite possible as I'm new to Backbone), but I can't find a list of the built-in events that I can bind to. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's listed in the backbone documentation, located at the link below:

http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

Comment: So it is! Don't know how I missed that - thought I had read the whole thing.

Comment: just one thing though - looking at the todo.js example app I see that it is using events like `dblclick` and `keypress` - how do those fit in?

Comment: Those are just ordinary events that you bind in `events` hash of view. For events generated by models and collections you bind with `Model.bind` or `Collection.bind`.

Comment: @Ivan is right. the events defined in the `events` hash are jquery / DOM events

Comment: I know this is old but a more specific link is http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Events-catalog

Comment: The page is unavailable now.